# Ubuntu server in Windows virtual machine

Tags: server, windows-10

I'm running Window Pro 10 on a x64 desktop with 8GB memory, 4 cores running at 2.7GHz and lots of disk space.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu server in a virtual machine? If yes, then please direct me to a good source for guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

1. Qemu [Download here](https://www.qemu.org/download/). You may also want to download QTemu [Qtemu GUI](https://qtemu.org/) is a GUI for QEMU that can be used in windows.
2. Virtual Box [Download here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

There are plenty of guides to install VMs. These are just some searchs...

1. Qemu [link](http://notonbluray.com/blog/getting-ubuntu-running-under-qemu-on-windows-7/)
2. Virtual BOX [link](https://hibbard.eu/install-ubuntu-virtual-box/)

The windows version should not be an issue.